# Make ImageView visible for set amount of time

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have an onClick method set in the xml layout file that triggers the vibration of the phone for 100ms at this point I have the ImageView Visibility set to visible so it can be seen. I want the ImageView to be set back to gone again when the vibration has stopped. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can start this method at the same time:

```
public void timerDelayRemoveView(float time, final ImageView v) {
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {           
        public void run() {                
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);      
        }
    }, time); 
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. You can animate the removal of your view by calling another method from here and passing your view as a parameter... to spice it up ;)