# set timeout Dialog in android?

Tags: android, dialog

I want to set timeout for Dialog (progress dialog) in android , to make the dialog disappears after a period of time (if there is No response for some action !)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The same approach as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795264/make-imageview-visible-for-set-amount-of-time) is verified to work (with long instead of float):

```
public void timerDelayRemoveDialog(long time, final Dialog d){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {                
            d.dismiss();         
        }
    }, time); 
}
```

Comment: Very handy. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 3):

You could always make a class called ProgressDialogWithTimeout and override the functionality of the show method to return a ProgressDialog and set a timer to do what you wish when that timer goes off. Example:

```
private static Timer mTimer = new Timer();
private static ProgressDialog dialog;

public ProgressDialogWithTimeout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public ProgressDialogWithTimeout(Context context, int theme) {
    super(context, theme);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static ProgressDialog show (Context context, CharSequence title, CharSequence message)
{
    MyTask task = new MyTask();
            // Run task after 10 seconds
    mTimer.schedule(task, 0, 10000);

    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, title, message);
    return dialog;
}

static class MyTask extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {
        // Do what you wish here with the dialog
        if (dialog != null)
        {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would call this in your code as so:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialogWithTimeout.show(this, "", "Loading...");
```