# How to make an AlertDialog disappear?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I am trying to integrate Twitter with my application and I thought to add an AlertDialog which will appear after users press a button and this AlertDialog will ask the users if they want to post a tweet(The tweet will be the same for all users, like a promo tweet). My question is if there is any way to make the Alert Dialog disappear after a few moments, like 5 seconds.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799540/set-timeout-dialog-in-android) but I am not completely sure how it works. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: the post you mention is all you can get. Having a handler to remove the AlertDialog d after "time" miliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your `Handler` that will deal to dismiss the dialog after some time, and declare thread that will pause the current thread and keep dialog for a some amount of time. In the `Runnable` of the thread make a statement that will sleep the thread for a some time, e.g `Thread.sleep(5000);` then use the Handler object to `sendMessage()`;, in the Handler `onHandleMessage()` method just do `dialog.dissmiss();`  After some operation, at point where you want keep the dialog, and start the thread using `myThread.start();`. Mind the instantiation of the thread each time when/where you need.

Comment: 2015 update. onHandleMessage seems to have been deprecated, try using handleMessage(Message msg) instead.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot access to UI from other threads so you must use handler to make modification on UI from the thread.

this is the code you use to make dialog disappear:

```
 d.dismiss();
```

and this is the handler code

```
Handler handler= new Handler()
```

use the method from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799540/set-timeout-dialog-in-android) and send to it time and dialog object