# How to set session timeout for my android application when using server

Tags: android, session, timeout

I am writing an Android App and I am trying to Login to the system ,
but the Loading Dialog Tack a lot time to disappear Although the system has completed the Login process .
How to set session timeout fro the Login process ??

Thank.

Answer (score 2):

Try this .

Set timeout in your code .

HttpURLConnection

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
// edit here ,change time
connection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
connection.setReadTimeout(20000);
```

OKHttp

```
private final OkHttpClient client;

public ConfigureTimeouts() throws Exception {
    client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795264/make-imageview-visible-for-set-amount-of-time) applied it. you can try this:

```
public void timerDelayRemoveDialog(long time, final Dialog d){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {                
            d.dismiss();         
        }
    }, time); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a andler and dismiss the dialog inside post delayed method.

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {                
        dialog_obj.dismiss();         
    }
}, 6000);
```

this code will dismiss the dialog after 6 seconds.